# Extjs 6.2.0 Combobox ValueField id and displayField name not working

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am trying to search from the combo by the name field and when I select the choosen text. I want that the id of the name field to be selected on the combo not the name.
When I save the id is saved but not loaded in the combo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eI9x.png)
I wrote this code which is working on Extjs 4.2.2 but not on Extjs 6.2.0.

```
        xtype: 'combo',
        name: 'keyword_id',
        value: Ext.isDefined(keyword_id) ? keyword_id:'',
        valueField: 'id',
        fieldLabel: 'Keyword id',
        itemId : "Keyword_id",
        displayField: 'name',
        margin: '10 0 0 20',
        width: 350,

        store : Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: this.autoLoad,
            sorters: { property: "name", direction: "ASC"},
            fields:[
                    {name:'id', mapping:'id'},
                    {name:'name', mapping:'name'}
                   ],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'proxy/proxy.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            }
        }),
        minChars: 1,
        hideTrigger: true,
        editable: true,         
        queryParam: 'name_like'
```

Comment: Create on fiddler for this.

Comment: I found another solution. I made 'blur' event that save the id put on valueField. Thank you.